# sas sorting and filtering by id

Tags: sas

I have columns named `id` and `key`. I sorted the data by `id` and I need to get the first 5 keys of every `id`.

```
PROC SQL OUTOBS=5;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_001 AS 
   SELECT DISTINCT t1.*      
      FROM work.DATA t1
      ORDER BY t1.id,
               t1.key DESC;
QUIT;
```

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention, this has nothing to do with SAS Macro!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OUTOBS=` option on your `PROC SQL` statement applies to the query as a whole, so with your example you would get only five rows returned.

The following code applies a counter `i` that resets each time a new `id` value is encountered. If the `i` value is five or less (i.e. first five rows for each `id`) then the row is written to the new dataset:

```
proc sort data=data;
  by id descending key;
run;

data query_001 (drop=i);
  set data;
    by id descending key;
    if first.id then i=0;
    i+1;
    if i <=5;
run;
```